# Windows Server 2012 R2 Issue Certificate in certificate authority

Tags: ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server, adfs3.0

I want to set up AD FS in windows server 2012 R2. I have already set up AD DS & also installed AD CS. After configuring certificate I want to add that in certificate authority section but It's not displaying in certificate template. Below is screenshot of certificate which I configured but it's not showing in template while issuing it to  the certificate authority in second screen shot.

[image: This certificate which I have created]

[image: But not showing in this templates]

Comment: Try to run the following command on CA server: `certutil -setreg ca\setupstatus +512` and then restart certificate services. And reopen CA management MMC console.

Comment: @Crypt32 Still it's not showing in certificate authority.